# GTK+ call function every x second

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

So I am working on writing a gui for an existing c application.

the gui is just a simple interface which would only display and not really feed back any information into the application. But I need to check a linked list if some new information is available.

Now I don`t want to use another thread to manually run the function to do this.

is there a way to 'hack' timed functions or callbacks into the GTK main loop? so that My function is called once every second or something like that. Of course my function is non-blocking.

I am writing in c.

Comment: How and from what is the new information coming from?

Comment: Polling a linked list for changes sounds awful in terms of UI programming technique. If you have control over the code in the data model, look at using a notification callback to update the UI when something in the list has changed.

Comment: I do have control but Generally I dont want to 'polute' the original code with calls to the gui...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GTK includes glib. glib is the core algorithm and data structure library used by gtk and many other gobject libraries. glib provides functions that will be called from the mainloop. glib is included when you include gtk.

You need to have a GSourceFunc as a callback the signature for a GSourceFunc is`gboolean
(*GSourceFunc) (gpointer user_data);`

```
gboolean YourCallBack(void* data)
{
    GSList list = (GSList*) data;
    // Check your list
    return TRUE; // return FALSE to remove the timeout
}
```

Somewhere else you have to register the function:

```
GSList* List; //This is a singly linked list provided by glib as well.
g_timeout_add_seconds(1, YourCallBack, List);
```

The first argument to g_timeout_add is the number of seconds between each call of the callback function, the second is the pointer to the GSourceFunc(the callback function) and the third argument is a pointer to data to be passed to the callback function.

**edit** A GSlist is typically a pointer is to one of the nodes(the first) in the list since the list can change, nodes can be prepended or removed from the list this is dangerous. Although this example shows how to use g_timeout_add_seconds you need a safer way to access your list then I present here. This does however show the mechanics of how to use g_timeout_add_x family of functions.

edit: You can use g_timeout_add to specify a callback for even smaller intervals than seconds, but if you don't need such precision, g_timeout_add_seconds cost fewer resources.

see: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add for more information.

Comment: Please use `g_timeout_add_seconds()` in examples that use full seconds for reasons mentioned in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Also, your example of linked list usage is broken. The question specifies that the list will change over time: with GSList that means that the pointer to list head can change. So you can't give `g_timeout_add_seconds()` the head-pointer itself (but you could give it a pointer that points to the current head pointer).

Comment: @jku I'll have to agree again.

Answer (score 4):

Read about [GTK main loop](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html) which is above [Glib main loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html). You'll need [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and perhaps [g_idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) etc...

You might also need to learn [Gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/). We cannot guess how is the new information coming into your application.

If you have a multi-threaded application, be aware that only the main thread can do GTK calls.